# Msg error : cannot invoke append with an argument list of type [any]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I think the array returns data of type Any but after i can't  convert in character type

```
let  tabCharacters  = Array(myWord.motModifié.characters)
// shuffle the array tabcharacter
let tabCharcatersMixed  = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: tabCharacters)
// i try to rebuild the word
myWord.contenumodifié = ""
// first letter
myWord.contenumodifié.append(myWord.debutMot)


//following letters but it 's not ok, error occurs at this level
for i in 0..<(tabCharcatersMixed.count - 1) {
    myWord.contenumodifié.append(tabCharcatersMixed[i])
}
```

I know this append is waiting character, so I would a systenm to convert any in character

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: ***cannot** invoke **append** with an argument list of type **[Any]*** aka *append expects a single item rather than an array* and you should cast `Any` to something more specific.

Comment: yes i understand that but i can't find the solution !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `arrayByShufflingObjects(in:)` returns `[Any]`.  You need to cast it to the type of the array you passed as `in:`.  In your case, it is `[Character]`.

```
let tabCharcatersMixed  = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: tabCharacters) as! [Character]
```

Next, you are trying to append these characters to `myWord.contenumodifié`.

If `myWord.contenumodifié` is `[Character]` then you can use `+=` to append the whole array:

replace this:

```
for i in 0..<(tabCharcatersMixed.count - 1) {
    myWord.contenumodifié.append(tabCharcatersMixed[i])
}
```

with this:

```
myWord.contenumodifié += tabCharcatersMixed
```

---

If `myWord.contenumodifié` is a `String`, you can create a `String` from the `[Character]` and then use `+=` to append:

replace this:

```
for i in 0..<(tabCharcatersMixed.count - 1) {
    myWord.contenumodifié.append(tabCharcatersMixed[i])
}
```

with this:

```
myWord.contenumodifié += String(tabCharcatersMixed)
```

Comment: I used your 2 snippets of code, in the first one, Ihave the same error. And the second, xcode orders me to write this part of code :    myWord.contenumodifié += String(describing: tabCharcatersMixed) but the result is no good. Thank you for your help, i wrote the solution below. Thanks for all

Comment: Did you add the `as! [Character]` cast to the `GKRandomSource` line like I suggested?  If you did that, you would no longer have `Any` to deal with`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't see the cast of GKRandomSource. Now it's ok, i didn't see any error

Answer (score 0):

I find  a solution :

```
for i in 0..<(tabCharcatersMixed.count ) {

    let thechar = tabCharcatersMixed[i] as! Character
    myWord.contenumodifié.append(thechar)
```

Comment: It is better to cast the `[Any]` array to `[Character]` at the point it is created than to cast each individual character.  The reason you know the array contains `Character`s is that `arrayByShufflingObjects` just reorders the array items it is given, and you are calling it with `[Character]`.  Appending the characters one by one in a loop is inefficient.  If you cast the array as I showed in my first line of code in my answer, you can then use `+=` to append the array all at once.